# JUNIT test case to test Web page

Tags: junit

I am new to write JUNIT test cases.

I am trying to write the unit test case for web page for one of the web application, where I would like to achieve the test case for the below scenario:

On click of icon new page will open, and it will display some relevant information which is fetched.

Comment: Start a server. User an HttpClient to fetch the page and afterwards check the page content.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test should verify an isolated piece of code. (Function, method, alghoritm, ...)

A well designed Web application is layered in front-end and back-end layers.
The click is triggered from the front-end layer. The fetch of informations should be a back-end service.
Your scenario isn't a unit test, is a integration test (between different layers/components of the application).

A good approach is to implement unit test (repetable, automatic) for all back-end services. Then execute test procedures (integration) with the web application.

Comment: Thanks @Sander.
Yeah I was exploring in the meanwhile and found this information.
So, now I need to write the test case for server side, whereby I am trying to fetch the information from DB by giving input as some ID.
Do you have any suggestions how should I proceed?